# Including professor's telephone number of application portal

Tags: graduate-admissions

I am an undergraduate student applying to grad programs in the U.S.; The application portal asks for the telephone number of my recommenders. However, one of my professors didn't reply to my email that asks for the number. Is it appropriate for me to include his phone number that appeared on his webpage of the university's department? Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Yes, that's fine.

It's extremely unlikely anyone will call anyone or that anyone will pick up, but that is why public numbers are listed publicly. Don't share home or cell numbers.

If the professor does not have a phone number listed, the department number is also OK.